# Remove time pattern in transcript data C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, replaceall

I am reading transcript text file in C# which looks like below. What is the best way to remove time pattern and extract only text and form as paragraph.

**What is best way to achieve output as i mentioned below? Regular Expressions?**

**Input of transcript file is like :**

```
 0:0:0.0 --> 0:0:0.820
 Really.

 0:0:1.840 --> 0:0:4.400
 I have meeting on 10th August 2020 at 10 A.M.

0:1:59.670 --> 0:2:1.720
I can extract  text without time pattern.

0:2:3.450 --> 0:2:7.280
All seems good.
```

**Ouput:** Need as like Paragraph.

```
Really. I have meeting on 10th August 2020 at 10 A.M. I can see extract text without time pattern. All seems good.
```

***Updated:***
**Code:**

I am able to try like below but still I feel for better optimization code. My code seems works if there is no date or time in sentences.

```
 var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
        //removing HTML tags and spl. characters
        string removedHTMltagsContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent.Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty).Replace("WEBVTT", "").Replace("-->", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(".",""), "<.*?>", String.Empty);

        //Removing all Digits
        var output = Regex.Replace(removedHTMltagsContent, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);

        //removing all multiple empty lines
        string resultString = Regex.Replace(output, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Comment: You could use regex, but as long as none of the transcripted text contains " --> " (transcripts usually don't) you can do this: `var justTheText = string.Join(' ', File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => line.Length > 0 && !line.Contains(" --> ")));`

Comment: Or just `var parsed = string.Join(" ", File.ReadLines("[Path]").Where(ln => ln.IndexOf("-->") < 0));`.

Comment: @Jimi Except you'll get the blank lines with that. Doesn't matter since it seems OP is hell bent on regex and ignoring other solutions.

Comment: Try `\s*\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ -->.*\s*`, replace with a space and trim the output https://regex101.com/r/vApcpL/1

Comment: `fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @"\s*(\d+:){2}.*-->.*\r\n", " ");` (just written here, without real concern for style :)

Comment: If you also want the lines with an empty line following in between, you might use `(?:\s*\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ -->.*\s*|\G)(\S.*)\s*` then replace with a space and group 1 ` $1` and trim the output to remove the leading space. https://regex101.com/r/LHb5RM/1

Answer (score 0):

You might match the time like pattern with the `-->` with leading and trailing whitespace chars to remove it, or match a non whitespace char till the rest of the line to keep in a group.

```
(?:\s*\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ -->.*\s*|\G)(\S.*)\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ -->.*\s*` Match the time like pattern with leading and trailing whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(\S.*)\s*` Match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line followed by 0+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cs*%5cd%2b%3a%5cd%2b%3a%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b+--%3e.*%5cs*%7c%5cG%29%28%5cS.*%29%5cs*&i=0%3a0%3a0.0+--%3e+0%3a0%3a0.820%0d%0a+Really.%0d%0a%0d%0a+0%3a0%3a1.840+--%3e+0%3a0%3a4.400%0d%0a+I+have+meeting+on+10th+August+2020+at+10+A.M.%0d%0a%0d%0a0%3a1%3a59.670+--%3e+0%3a2%3a1.720%0d%0aI+can+extract++text+without+time+pattern.%0d%0a%0d%0a0%3a2%3a3.450+--%3e+0%3a2%3a7.280%0d%0aAll+seems+good.%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+is+a+line+and%2c+%0d%0a%0d%0athis+is+also+a+line%0d%0a%0d%0a0%3a2%3a3.450+--%3e+0%3a2%3a7.280%0d%0aAll+seems+good.%0d%0agood&r=+%241) | [.NET demo](https://ideone.com/Ftkc31)

In the replacement use a space and group 1  `$1`

If there is a leading space, you could trim the string to remove it.

[image]

Example code

```
string pattern = @"(?:\s*\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ -->.*\s*|\G)(\S.*)\s*";
string input = @"...";
            
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, " $1").Trim());
```

Output

```
Really. I have meeting on 10th August 2020 at 10 A.M. I can extract  text without time pattern. All seems good.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simpler techniques:

```
        var contents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var lines = contents.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //gets you an array with text lines excluding empty ones
        var result = lines.ToList()
            .Where((l, i) => i % 2 != 0) //get only even lines
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, l) => sb.Append(l)) //aggregate them in a string builder
            .ToString(); // get your string
```